# C pointers - Point to the same address

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int *a, int *b);

void foo(int *a, int *b) {
    *a = 5;
    *b = 6;
    a = b;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    foo(&a, &b);
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why a = b (foo) doesn't work? printf outputs "5, 6"
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

It does work; it just doesn't do what you think it does.

In `foo()`, `a = b` changes the pointer `a` to point to whatever `b` points to.  It has no effect on anything outside of the function; it only changes the pointers.

If you want to change the value of the int pointed to by `a` to be the same as the value of the int pointed to by `b`, you need to use `*a = *b`, similar to how you do the assignments in the function already.

Comment: @cnoob:  Yes.  In C, everything is passed by value.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `foo()` ends with its local variables pointing to the same addres, the one of stored in *b*. This change is not reflected in `main()`, the caller.

I you liked to actually do this and make this change pemanent, then you would have to pass a pointer to a pointer to `foo()` (so you can change them), instead of their simple values:

```
void foo(int **a, int **b) {
    **a = 5;
    **b = 6;
    *a = *b;
}
```

I have just observed that your code is incompatible with that modification, anyway, since you cannot change two normal variables to point to each other. You'd have to also modify `main()` this way:

```
int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    int * ptrA = &a;
    int * ptrB = &b;

    foo(&ptrA, &ptrB);
    printf("%d, %d (%d, %d)", *ptrA, *ptrB, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't like the look of `int ptrA = &a;` - did you mean `int *ptrA = &a;`?

Comment: Here it is the same: 5, 6 instead of 6, 6

Comment: If you show the values of a and b, the int variables, they will remain the same. Show the values of *ptrA and *ptrB and you will get 6,6. This is included in the answer: if you read it thorougly, you will see that the printf() of main() was modified.

Answer (score 2):

Using a pseudo-memory map,

In `main()`,

```
    a      b
 --------------
|  5   |   6   | <- data
 --------------
 [1000]  [1004]  <- address
```

In the function `foo()`,

```
    a        b      ( local to foo(), different from the a & b in main() )
 ----------------
|  1000  | 1004  | <- data
 ----------------
  [2000]   [2004]  <- address
```

So, when in `foo()`'s scope,

```
*a = 5;   // store 5 in int variable a
*b = 6;   // store 6 in int variable b
 a = b;   // copies contents of pointer variable b to a
```

So the final map in `foo()`'s scope is:

```
    a        b
 ----------------
|  1004  | 1004  | <- data
 ----------------
  [2000]   [2004]  <- address
```

Answer (score 1):

In `foo`, `a` and `b` are separate local variables. Setting them to have the same value has no effect on the previous values - the last line of `foo` currently does nothing, basically.

Within `foo`, `a` is *initially* a pointer to the same location as `a` in `main`, and `b` is a pointer to the same location as `b` in main. The last line just makes the value of `a` in `foo` the same as `b` - namely a pointer to the same location as `b` in main. So if you add a line

```
*a = 7;
```

at the end of `foo`, then you'd see output of "5, 7".

(Your code would definitely be easier to talk about if you used different variable names in `main` and `foo`, by the way.)

If you're trying to make `a` and `b` within `main` "aliased" to each other, you're not going to be successful. They're separate local variables on the stack, and will remain so. You can't make the stack "shrink" to alias the two, whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're going after... if it's to get `a` and `b` to contain the same value, try `*a = *b`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when `foo` is called, the values of the pointers are **copied**  into the function. If you want to change the values of the pointers themselves, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer into the function.

Comment: @cnoob: You haven't said what you want to happen, so there's no "solution".

Comment: sorry. I want to have the output 6, 6 instead of 5, 5.

Answer (score 0):

a and b are local to the function foo (they are on the stack), when program returns from the function data on the stack is lost. when you assign b to a, you are only modifying memory addresses on the stack, not their values.