# can there be two pointers pointing the same string?

Tags: c

```
char *str = "hello";
```

In a code like this, can I make another pointer
(for example,

```
char *strptr = NULL;
```

and make this to point String str, "hello"? (like this:  **strptr->str->"hello"** or **strptr->"hello"<-str**)

I tried double pointer, or changing the pointer type.. but all failed

Comment: `strptr->str->"hello" or strptr->"hello"<-str` - none of these is valid. What is your problem? How to copy one variable to another? Please read a C book. Asking particular questions here will not give you the whole picture.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 2 pointers can indeed point to the same number.

```
const char *a = "str";
const char *b = a;
```

They now point to the same string.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * str = "hello";
```

You now want a second pointer just like the first. So declare it just like the first, `char * strptr`.

Now it should point at the same thing as well. Now how would you do that? How do you make some thing B, which has the same type as A, hold the same information as A?

You assign it.

```
char * strptr = str;
```

Take note that both `str` and `strptr` are currently pointing at read-only memory, and should *probably* be `const` for that reason. (Unless you really know what you're doing and want to use the pointers for pointing at something else later on.)

Comment: Daisy chaining like @DevSolar suggested works but for more elaborate answers check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815400/c-pointers-point-to-the-same-address

Answer (score 1):

And the other part of the question:

```
char * str = "hello";
char ** strptr = &str;
```

Comment: only this code shows exactly what I want! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
char *strptr = str;
```

So you will get strptr -> "hello" <- str

Answer (score 0):

Pointers reference a memory address. You can obtain the memory address itself by using the `&` operator, double pointers point to a memory address that points to another memory address so you would have what you described as `strcpr->str->"hello"` which is a pointer that points to another pointer. Here's an example:

```
char *str = "Hello!";
char **strp = &str;
// The memory address for the string
printf("%p\n", &str);
// This would print the same address as the previous command as
// they both reference the same string
printf("%p\n", strp);
// This prints the value of your string
printf("%s\n", *strp);
```

Notice how the double pointer points to the memory address of the first string. The output should be `Hello!`.

Edit: C syntax

Comment: since when `cout` hsa been C?

Comment: Thank you~!! great help! if you don't mind, can I ask little more?

Comment: if you don't mind, can I ask little more? `char *str = "str";
 char **strptr = &str;
 char a[] = "abc";
 *strptr = a;
 printf("%s", *strptr);
 str = "no";
 printf("%s", *strptr); `

Comment: why the result of this code is abcno? (i want abcabc..)

Comment: You're changing the value of the variable itself here `*strptr = a;` and here `str ="no"`. Pointers don't contain the value of the variable itself, they only point to the memory address where the value is stored. You might want to take a read about how pointers work, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) and [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-pointer-to-pointer/) are some resources.